# FullCalendar Show events in two months?

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to display two months in the calendar, namely July and August. All the other months should be hidden, for example the next month or previous month button should be disabled.

For example, if one event is span from 29th July to 3rd August that should be display in the same window of two months view.

Is this possible with FullCalendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using two calendars on one page; see http://jsfiddle.net/wijgerden/W77vt/ for an example using the recent FullCalendar v2.0.2 release.

This example still has buttons for previous, next, and today enabled (also showing how `viewRender` can be used to synchronise the two calendars). But you can remove those by changing `right: 'prev,next today'` to just `right: ''` on the `cal0` configuration (in JavaScript).